Decorator / functionality for inheriting an arbitrary number of classes
I want to create functionality for a data class to be able to inherit 0..N mix-ins in Python whilst still returning the original data class object.
I have a preliminarily working solution, albeit very ugly and not very pythonic.
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass
 
@dataclass
class Customer:
    salary = 0
    monthlyBonus = 0
    latestClassification = ""
    
    
class SalaryMixin:
    def get_salary(self: Any) -> float:
        return self.salary
 
 
class customerInformationMixin:
    def get_latest_classification(self: Any) -> str:
        return self.latestClassification
    
def create_customer(*mixins: Type) -> Customer:
    customer = Customer()
    for mixin in mixins:
        mixin_methods = [func for func in dir(mixin) if callable(getattr(mixin, func)) and not func.startswith("__")]
        for method in mixin_methods:
            setattr(customer, method, getattr(mixin(), method))
    return customer

Ultimately I would like a function create_customer() that will accept any number of mix-ins and inherit its functionality.

Another way of achieving the desired functionality is renaming the Customer dataclass to BaseCustomer and then create this:
    class Customer(BaseCustomer, *mixins):
        pass
    return Customer()

However I would like to leave the extra class out.

Your solution in the comment is fine, much better than the one in the question. It is unclear why you want to "leave the extra class out". What exactly is the downside you want to avoid?

@blhsing I would ideally like the function to actually return an object BaseCustomer, whilst this will return a Customer object. (The solution from the comment).

But why? Customer as a subclass of BaseCustomer would still allow isinstance(Customer(), BaseCustomer) to return true. BaseCustomer is defined without those mixins, so you simply have to create a subclass in order to introduce mixins. It's how inheritance works. There is no practical downside. You should clarify exactly what issues creating a subclass is causing to you.

@blhsing The problem it is causing me is the addition of another abstraction layer. I have enough abstractions in my project as is. I would like to seperate the logic from the dataclass, and this introduces complexity.
Furthermore, I would like to write tests. Should tests then be written for BaseCustomer or Customer? Maybe I am confusing my self.

The abstraction layer of a subclass with multiple inheritance actually simplifies the logics of how methods from the mixins are introduced to a Customer object by hiding the complexity behind the MRO mechanism with declarative base classes. The alternatives include monkeypatching the original class with mixin methods (like you do in the question) and using a metaclass to dynamically register mixins into the MRO, both of which complicate the logics and will most certainly fail checks from static analytic tools.

Okay. I stand corrected. Maybe I do like the solution better as per my comment. Just a small note: isinstance(Customer(), BaseCustomer) returns false. But I think you meant isinstance(customer, BaseCustomer) where customer = create_customer()?

I'm referring to the dynamically created Customer in the solution in your comment, where Customer() is returned.

@JOKKINATOR When you finalize your solution, you should answer your own question and post the final to benefit others who may have same question.

The easiest, most maintainable solutions is:
def create_customer(*mixins: Type) -> Type[Customer]: 
    class Customer(BaseCustomer, *mixins): 
        pass 
return Customer() 

